# Which C99-compiler (Clang vs. GCC) is closer to standard on const structure fields?

Tags: c, gcc, constants, clang, c99

I have code like this:

```
$ cat test.c 
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
    const int x;
} SX;

static SX mksx(void)
{
    return (SX) { .x = 10 };
}

void fn(void)
{
    SX sx;
    while((sx = mksx()).x != 20)
    {
        printf("stupid code!");
    }
}
```

And 2 opinions about its correctness:

```
$ for i in gcc clang; do echo "$i SAYS:"; $i -c -std=c99 -pedantic -Werror test.c; done
gcc SAYS:
test.c: In function ‘fn’:
test.c:15:2: error: assignment of read-only variable ‘sx’
  while((sx = mksx()).x != 20)
  ^
clang SAYS:
```

Which compiler is right?

Comment: I would say that you should take into account GCC, it is so widely used (and even the latest GCC 4.8.1 gives the same error). This pragmatic reason should be enough to avoid such coding.

Comment: He might simply be asking to know which compiler to file a bug report against. (And an equally valid answer might be "none of them")

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C99 standard says in 6.5.16:2:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

and in 6.3.2.1:1:

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that does not have array type, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and **if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type**.

So GCC is right to warn.

In addition, the clause 6.5.16:2 is in a “Constraints” section of the C99 standard, so a conforming compiler is required to emit a diagnostic for a program that breaks the clause. It is still undefined behavior: the compiler can still do what it wants after the diagnostic is emitted. But there has to be a message. In consequence, Clang is behaving in a non-conforming manner here.

Comment: 6.5.15:2 is a constraint violation, not merely undefined behavior. A conforming compiler *must* issue a diagnostic for any program that violates a constraint (C99 5.1.3.3); clang fails to do so.

Comment: @KeithThompson As I was typing that very part I thought “Keith Thompson would check whether we are talking about a constraint violation here”. And I somehow managed to overlook the word.

Comment: I wonder what the intended purpose of that "feature" is?  In some other languages like C# which allow "readonly" qualifiers on struct members, the qualifier indicates that the member will not be changed *except* by overwriting the whole struct; such a construct can be useful with a structure that is supposed to uphold certain invariants (one would typically construct instances using a function that returns an suitably-initialized structure).  I can't think of any use case for a C struct having a const-qualified field with C99 semantics.

Answer (score 3):

`const` variable can't be modified after initialization, otherwise it's undefined behavior.

<del>Since it is undefined behavior, I think one can say both gcc and clang follow the standard. (Although gcc's choice seems better, it deserves a warning)</del> (See **EDIT** below)

The only way to give the variable `x` a value with defined behavior is to initialize it:

```
SX sx = { .x = 10 };
```

**EDIT**: As @Keith Thompson comments below, it's more than just undefined behavior in this case:

> #### C99 §6.5.16 Assignment operators
>
> **Constraints**
>
> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

This is a constraint, and according to:

> #### C99 §5.1.1.3 Diagnostics
>
> A conforming implementation shall produce at least one diagnostic message (identified in
> an implementation-defined manner) if a preprocessing translation unit or translation unit
> contains a violation of any syntax rule or constraint, even if the behavior is also explicitly specified as undefined or implementation-defined. Diagnostic messages need not be produced in other circumstances.

A compiler must issue a diagnostic for any program that violates a constraint.

Back to the question, gcc is correct is generate a warning, while clang fails to do so.

Comment: why would you use a compound literal for initialization. `SX sx = { .x = 10 };`  should work as well

Comment: @JensGustedt True, I just followed what OP used in the code of the question.

Comment: It's not merely undefined behavior; it's a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic from any conforming compiler. See [Pascal's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18529041/827263) and my comment.