# Why does this discarding of const-qualification not result in any warning?

Tags: c, constants

```
struct istruct {
   const int i;
};
const int i = 1;
struct istruct is = {1};

void *voidp_i = &i; // warning: discards 'const' qualifier
void *voidp_is = &is; // no warning
```

For all intents and purposes, a `struct istruct` seems to be interpreted as a const-qualified type. If that is true, then wouldn't it make sense for the last line to emit a warning as well?

Comment: I think because `is` has no `const` qualifier. The struct member is but the struct itself not.

Comment: But `&is` is not a constant, `(&is)->i` is. What if there were two members: one was const, while another was not?

Comment: Since you've put the `const` inside the type definition, when you convert the pointer back from `void` the field will still be `const`-qualified, unless you convert the pointer to a different type altogether and start getting involved with all of the potential associated problems that might have.

Comment: Allow me to share some of my experience as is (i.e. no standard quotes): For at least some of the compilers (mostly embedded in my environment) do not expect any effect of a const qualifier within a struct type. Only the const qualifier of a variable definition of a struct type is relevant. In embedded environments, const variables can get linked into physically non.writeable memory to realise the const effect. Parts of variables cannot be linked into different memories. At least that is how I explained it to myself. Comments to enlighten me are welcome.

Comment: Worth a glance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527984/which-c99-compiler-clang-vs-gcc-is-closer-to-standard-on-const-structure-fiel/18529041#18529041

Comment: Also: https://matt.sh/sytycc

Comment: @Yunnosch Regarding the (non-)effect of `const` qualifiers: I was trying to make a read-only struct for the purpose of being as explicit as possible for the user of such a struct (I am designing an API).

Comment: @Yunnosch Interesting, that blog post identifies the exact same thing at the bottom, but does not explain either why the behavior is the way it is.

Comment: @Leushenko OK, interesting observation. However, it looks to me like the *only* correct thing you can do with that pointer is casting it back, or use it in places where a `const void *` is expected. So wouldn't that warrant a warning, in your opinion?

Answer (score 2):

```
void *voidp_is = &is;
```

Here `&is` is of type `struct istruct *` and has no `const` qualifier, only the member `i` is `const`. Note that writing to the `const` member of the struct (for example `((struct istruct *) voidp_is)->i=0;`) will lead to undefined behavior since you are modifying a `const int`. (C2011, 6.7.3/6)

```
void *voidp_i = &i;
```

In this example `&i` is of type `int const *` and the `const` qualifier is discarded at the initialization.

Comment: I see `is` defined as variable of type `struct ìstruct` not `struct istruct*`. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes but `&is` is therefore of type `struct istruct *`.

Comment: Ah, I see You are referring to the init value for voidp_is. I missed that. Maybe you want to phrase for the partially blind, like me... ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch I added the definitions. I think it is now more clear what I am referring to.

Comment: Thanks. Would you like to improve by discussing what happens when attempting to write to `((struct istruct*) voidp_is)->i=0;`? I'd be interested, because my experience lets me not expect a discard warning even then.

Comment: @Yunnosch Thank you for your suggestions. I added that writing to it will lead to undefined behavior. I also would not expect a warning since there is nothing discarded, it is just writing to a `const int`.

Comment: This is "the obvious answer" (no offense intended), but that seems a little shallow to me. OK, the syntax between the two is different but that seems to be about the *only* difference. If that is true, then both constructs have similar risks associated and therefore warrant similar warnings from the compiler. No?

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek The difference is that the struct itself does not have a `const` qualifier, so there is no reason for the compiler to throw a warning. Also note that `void *voidp_i = &is.i;` throws a warning for the same reason it does for `i`.

Comment: @Osiris Yes, I see that syntactic difference. As for a "reason for the compiler to throw a warning", those reasons could be anyone's guess because there are no standards specifying when a warning should be generated. A good reason *for me* to be warned in this case is to make me aware that I am probably doing something that may lead to undefined behavior.